# Normalization to unity, Projection Operators in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, probability, quantum-states, normalization

I have a question about something that is stated in Sakurai's MQM. It's written that if one runs a sequence of selective measurements (namely, a sequence of independent stern-gerlach apparatuses) where the first filter selects some particular eigenstate $|a'\rangle$ and rejects all others, then the second one selects some particular $|b'\rangle$ and the third selects some particular $|c'\rangle$ (both analogously to the first one), then the probability of obtaining $|c'\rangle$, **when the first beam is normalized to unity**, is given by:
$$ Prob = |\langle c'|b'\rangle |^2 |\langle b'|a' \rangle|^2 $$
Shouldn't we worry about the normalization of the resulting ket from the first selective measurement? How do I know if after applying the projection operator along $|a'\rangle$ I will end up with a normalized-to-unity state ket, and the same for the projection onto $|b'\rangle$ and eventually onto $|c'\rangle$. In formulas:
$$ \langle \alpha|\alpha\rangle = 1, |a'\rangle \langle a'|\alpha \rangle \equiv |\gamma \rangle \xrightarrow{?} \langle \gamma| \gamma \rangle = 1, |b'\rangle \langle b'|\gamma \rangle \equiv |\beta \rangle \xrightarrow{?} \langle \beta|\beta \rangle = 1 \cdots$$

Comment: The probability of absorption and the probability of non-absorption between them should add up to 1. If you renormalize after each step then you are effectively asking "what is the probability of transmission through the filter given that the system is transmitted"

Comment: What do you mean when you say "between them"? If I do not renormalize,  I can't really talk of probability anyway, since probability has to satisfy certain conditions. Nevertheless, I'm not sure I understood your point correctly to be fair, so I'm not saying what you stated is necessarily wrong.  Maybe you could rephrase your argument in a different way, so that it becomes clearer, maybe with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the probability of getting a certain state $\left|b\right>$ upon measurement of an initial state $\left|a\right>$ is given by
$$\tag1P=\frac{\left<a|b\right>\left<b|a\right>}{\left<b|b\right>\left<a|a\right>}$$
which, if both states are normalised, i.e. $\left<a|a\right>=1=\left<b|b\right>$ then it reduces to the standard usual expression $P=\left|\left<b|a\right>\right|^2$

Needless to say, everybody hates the denominators and we almost always only talk about normalised states. i.e. in physics literature, all states are normalised unless clearly labelled to not be normalised.

---

You are definitely correct to worry about what is actually happening to a state upon measurement. Earlier, we have defined that $P=\left|\left<b|a\right>\right|^2$. This means that
$$\tag2\left<b|a\right>=e^{i\varphi}\sqrt P\qquad\text{for some}\qquad\varphi\in(-\pi,+\pi]$$
In the last equation of your question, it is clear that you think that measuring that a state changed from $\left|a\right>$ to $\left|b\right>$ results in
$$\tag3\left|a\right>\qquad\to\qquad\left|b\rangle\langle b|a\right>=\left|b\right>e^{i\varphi}\sqrt P$$
and I have to give to you that this is indeed a rather reasonable guess. However, the trouble is that this is a non-normalised state.

Instead, what happens is that
$$\tag4\left|a\right>\qquad\to\qquad\left|b\right>e^{i\varphi}\qquad\text{alone, but with probability $P$ of this happening}$$
this resulting state is both normalised and the pure phase factor drops out or cancels out when you do other stuff to this state. I leave it to you to verify that the scheme I am telling you will reproduce the same probability propagation that you cited from Sakurai.

In essence, what each specific measurement that quantum theory will furnish you with, are *conditional probabilities.* This ties in precisely well with the comment by "By Symmetry", namely that

> If you renormalise after each step then you are effectively asking "what is the probability of transmission through the filter given that the system is transmitted?"

That is, you could have jolly well continued working with $\left|b\rangle\langle b|a\right>$ and gotten the correct results, except that you would be working with non-normalised states, and the final probability you are getting will be the overall probability, not conditional probabilities that require a product of a chain of them. It is clear that you can get all the correct results either way, provided you stick very carefully to that scheme's particular rules of operation. Note that you would have a lot of square roots of the denominators that appeared in Equation (1) flying around—That is why physicists have been trained to use conditional probabilities rather than overall probabilities: it is just a total chore to keep having to remember that states are not normalised if you use this scheme.

---

You might wonder why it was necessary to keep the $e^{i\varphi}$ if the pure overall phase is not going to affect results. However, it does. If you take the measured state and perform interference measurements, it is possible to engineer for this phase to play a part.

But more commonly, we have to keep this phase information because most measurements come with degenerate eigenspaces. Then, the projection onto the degenerate eigenspace will preserve the original state's phase relations between eigenstates within this degenerate eigenspace, at most changing them all with the same phase. In this way, we can again create interference patterns and what not.

I think I'd better give an example. Consider measuring the total orbital angular momentum $\ell$ by some crazy method, but leaving the magnetic angular momentum quantum numbers $m$ undisturbed, then
$$
\begin{align}
  \left|a\right>
&=\hat{\mathbb I}\left|a\right>
 =\sum_b\left|b\rangle\langle b|a\right>\tag5\\
&=\left|\ell=0,m=0
           \rangle\langle0,0|a\right>
 +\left|1,-\rangle\langle1,-|a\right>
 +\left|1,0\rangle\langle1,0|a\right>
 +\left|1,+\rangle\langle1,+|a\right>+\cdots\tag6\\
&=\left|0,0\right>e^{i\vartheta}\sqrt{P_0}+\sqrt{P_1}\left(
  \left|1,-\right>e^{i\alpha}\sqrt{P_\alpha}
 +\left|1,0\right>e^{i\beta }\sqrt{P_\beta }
 +\left|1,+\right>e^{i\gamma}\sqrt{P_\gamma}\right)+\cdots\tag7
\end  {align}
$$
will, upon measuring $\ell=1$ (with probability $P_1$ of this happening), turn into
$$\tag8
  \left|1,-\right>e^{i\alpha}\sqrt{P_\alpha}
 +\left|1,0\right>e^{i\beta }\sqrt{P_\beta }
 +\left|1,+\right>e^{i\gamma}\sqrt{P_\gamma}
$$
preserving the phases $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ i.e. if they were originally some specific superposition, then they will continue to be such a specific superposition after the measurement. Of course, in order for the probabilities to come out correct, we must also have $P_\alpha+P_\beta+P_\gamma=1$. Note, in particular, that $\left<1,-|a\right>=\sqrt{P_1}e^{i\alpha}\sqrt{P_\alpha}$, i.e. the cascading conditional probabilities are already correctly handled here.

Answer (score 1):

> ...is given by:
> $$ Prob = |\langle c'|b'\rangle |^2 |\langle b'|a' \rangle|^2 $$

> Shouldn't we worry about the normalization of the resulting ket from the first selective measurement?

To the extent we should worry about it, we already have [all agreed on a rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics#State_change_due_to_measurement) so that we never have to worry about it again.

Namely, after a measurement on a pure state $|\Psi\rangle$, where the measurement results is the eigenvalue $\alpha$ associated with the projector $\hat\Pi_\alpha$, the resulting "collapsed" state is:
$$
|\Psi\rangle \to \frac{\Pi_\alpha|\Psi\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle \Psi|\Pi_\alpha^\dagger\Pi_\alpha|\Psi\rangle}}\;,
$$
such that the "collapsed" state vector is forced to be normalized "by hand."

If you have non-degenerate eigenvalues the projectors are just:
$$
\Pi_{a'} = |a'\rangle\langle a'|
$$
$$
\Pi_{b'} = |b'\rangle\langle b'|
$$
$$
\Pi_{c'} = |c'\rangle\langle c'|\;.
$$

So, for example, after measuring $a'$ the "collapsed" state vector is:
$$
|\Psi\rangle \to \frac{|a'\rangle\langle a'|\Psi\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle \Psi|a'\rangle\langle a'|a'\rangle\langle a'|\Psi\rangle}} = e^{i\phi}|a'\rangle\;,
$$
where $e^{i\phi} = \frac{\langle a'|\Psi\rangle}{|\langle a'|\Psi\rangle|}$.

So the resulting state vector is physically equivalent to the state vector:
$$
|a'\rangle\;.
$$

> How do I know if after applying the projection operator along $|a'\rangle$ I will end up with a normalized-to-unity state ket,

This is a well-known (for almost a hundred years) part of the Born rule (or measurement rule). It is just an axiom of quatum mechanics that the "collapsed" state is normalized "by hand," as discussed above.

---

Once I measure the value $a'$ for a non-degenerate eigenvalue, the state is normalized and is:
$$
|a'\rangle
$$

Given this is the state, the probability to measure $b'$ is:
$$
P_{a'}(b') = |\langle b'|a'\rangle|^2
$$

Given that $b'$ is measured, and is non-degenerate, the state collapses again to:
$$
|b'\rangle\;.
$$

Now, I can calculate the probability to measure $c'$ given I am in the state $b'$, which is:
$$
P_{b'}(c') = |\langle c'|b'\rangle|^2\;.
$$

The probability to measure $b'$ given $a'$ *and* $c'$ given $b'$ is the product of the individual probabilities:
$$
P_{b'}(c')P_{a'}(b') = |\langle c'|b'\rangle|^2|\langle b'|a'\rangle|^2
$$